# Opening a File whose Name Contains a Space

Tags: excel, wsh, vba

I have some simple Excel VBA code that opens non-Excel files like:

```
Sub scriptTest()
    Set objshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    objshell.Run ("C:\TestFolder\Book1.pdf")
    Set objshell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Running this opens the file in the Acrobat Reader.  However if I try to open a file whose name contains a **space** character like:

```
Sub scriptTest()
    Set objshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    objshell.Run ("C:\TestFolder\Bo ok1.pdf")
    Set objshell = Nothing
End Sub
```

I get:

[image]

Both files open fine if I use the `Run` command from the Windows Start menu.  How can I overcome this problem ??

Comment: @MykolaShchetinin  Thanks for the suggestion, but neither forward slash or backslash had any effect.

Comment: @YowE3K  PERFECT!  Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Why use COM in VBA  at all, theres in no need for late binding this stuff when you have full access to the Windows APIs.

Comment: @Lankymart  **Good idea!**  I will pursue it.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent [CreateProcess function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) would be where to start.

Comment: @Lankymart Thank you !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When executing the statement `objshell.Run ("C:\TestFolder\Bo ok1.pdf")`, you are asking the shell to execute the command

```
C:\TestFolder\Bo ok1.pdf
```

This is interpreted as being a request to execute the program `C:\TestFolder\Bo.exe` with a parameter of `ok1.pdf`.

You actually want the shell to execute the command

```
"C:\TestFolder\Bo ok1.pdf"
```

where the quotation marks are used by the command interpreter to "group" parts of the command together.

To obtain that command, you need to execute the statement

```
objshell.Run """C:\TestFolder\Bo ok1.pdf"""
```

Comment: Wow, 6 votes for pointing out when you want to escape a quoted string you need to double the quotes. Seriously, this hasn't been answered before?

Comment: @Lankymart It wasn't actually that the quotation marks needed to be escaped, it was that the quotation marks needed to be used.  (If you find a good duplicate, please feel free to close the question, and ping me so I can delete the answer.)