# open file using pattern matching VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with opening a file using pattern matching. The purpose is opening a file which has a patern like this : `extraction _ 20180630 _ Data - Updated.Xlsx`. This part of the file name : `201806` is set by the users via an input box function using variables as text. The goal is to open this file knowing that the dates can change depending on the target chosen by the users (year and month) .

Here is my code :

```
Sub OpenFile 
    Dim Directory As Text
    Dim File As Text 
    Dim MainPath As Text
    Dim Y As Text
    Dim M As Text 

    Directory = "C:\Desktop\Folder\"

    Y = InputBox  ("Please Choose your target Year such as 2017")
    M = InputBox ("Please Choose your target Month such as 06 for June")

    ' File name format = "extraction _ 20180630 _ Data - Updated _V5.2.xlslx"
    File = "extraction _" &  Y  & M 
    MainPath = Directory  & File 
    Filename = Dir (MainPath & "*_ Data - Updated _*")

    On Error  Resume Next

    ' after several Checking, the MainPath is Correct. the issue is whithin the second part 
    Workbooks.Open MainPath & Filename

    If Err.Number = 1004
        MsgBox " The file was not found"
        Err.Clear
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Quit 
     End If
End Sub
```

As You can imagine, this code generates an

> error 1004

and I checked the main path which is correct. The issue is with the second part of Filename as Follows `*_ Data - Updated _*`)

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you add `MsgBox MainPath & "|" & Filename` to your code, what Path and FileName does it *actually* try to open?  This might help you find which line the error is on

Comment: Using spaces ( ` `) in filenames is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I guess the issue is that the second part it's not taken into account by what it starts with " * ". usually, I use this terms '*' with someting before you know.

Comment: @Luuklag. I know that, but it's not my choice. I have to handle it with this format with space :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening a File whose Name Contains a Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593437/opening-a-file-whose-name-contains-a-space)

Comment: @Chronocida. MsgBox Display what follows : C:\Desktop\Folder\extraction _ 201806|

Comment: Maybe, there is a vba function which generates the last day of each month automatically in order to  set a path with the full file name.

Comment: @DataScientist Yup: `DateSerial(Year(Now()),Month(Now())+1,0)` will give the last day of the current month, or `DateSerial(cLng(Y),cLng(M)+1,0)` to get the last day based on your code.  The fact that there is nothing after the "|" on the MessageBox means that `Filename` was not found by the `Dir` function.

Comment: Once you get the `FileName` working correctly, you should also be opening the file `Directory & Filename`, not `Mainpath & Filename` - otherwise you try to open `C:\Desktop\Folder\extraction _ 201806extraction _ 20180630 _ Data - Updated.Xlsx` instead of `C:\Desktop\Folder\extraction _ 20180630 _ Data - Updated.Xlsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussion in comments above, try the following:

```vb
' File name format = "extraction _ 20180630 _ Data - Updated _V5.2.xlsx"
File = "extraction _" & Format(DateSerial(CInt(y), CInt(M) + 1, 0), "yyyymmdd") & "_ Data - Updated*"
Filename = Dir(Directory & File)

On Error Resume Next

' after several Checking, the MainPath is Correct. the issue is whithin the second part
If Len(Filename) > 1 Then
    Workbooks.Open Directory & Filename
Else
    MsgBox "Unable to find file for pattern """ & File & """ in location " & Directory, vbCritical
End If
```

Here is a version that will also roll back up to 3 months looking for the latest file:

```vb
' File name format = "extraction _ 20180630 _ Data - Updated _V5.2.xlsx"
Dim lRollBack As Integer
For lRollBack = 0 To 3
    File = "extraction _" & Format(DateSerial(CInt(y), CInt(M) + 1 - lRollBack, 0), "yyyymmdd") & "_ Data - Updated*"
    Filename = Dir(Directory & File)
    If Len(Filename) > 1 Then Exit For 'Stop after we find a match
Next lRollBack

On Error Resume Next

' after several Checking, the MainPath is Correct. the issue is whithin the second part
If lRollBack <= 3 Then
    If lRollBack > 0 Then
        MsgBox "We had to roll back by " & CStr(lRollBack) & " month(s)", vbInformation
    End If
    Workbooks.Open Directory & Filename
Else
    MsgBox "Unable to find file for pattern """ & File & """ in location " & Directory, vbCritical
End If
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick reply. Just to understand why there is + 1 in what follow : CInt(M) + 1 ?

Comment: @DataScientist Because the *last* day of **this** month (e.g. `DateSerial(2018,09,30)`) is the same as the *zeroth* day of **next** month (e.g. `DateSerial(2018,10,0)`) - much like how `DateSerial(2018,13,1)` is the same as `DateSerial(2019,1,1)`

Comment: @ Chronocidal : Last Question :  Sometimes. I need to open the file of the previous month when the current is not available. I was Thinking  of using M = M - 1 if the first is not available, but the Variable M is text. Do you know if is there a way to  handle it with Format(DateSerial(CInt(y), CInt(M) + 1, 0), "yyyymmdd") directly ? Thanks Again

Comment: @DataScientist I have added a loop that rolls back up to 3 months

Comment: @ Chronocidal that awesome!! big Thanks. Realy usefull. I hope that handle the first month as January to go back to the previous year. thnks a lot sir